# Can we have shipping optional in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a project which have some products which need shipping while some others don't need it. Is there some way I can make shipping optional? (p.s. Did not paste any code as it might not be required)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the spree's `Order` model you can notice that it has hardcoded `delivery` step - https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L48

You can customize the checkout steps using the following guide - https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html

`remove_checkout_step :shipping`